# Comparar dois valores do array com foreach

Tags: php

Possuo um `Foreach` em um array para montar uma determinada tabela, o array esta ordenado, porém preciso remover os valores duplicados e deixar apenas algumas informações do mesmo e não todas. Minha ideia é comparar o `n` com `n-1` onde `n` é a posição do array, porém minha duvida fica em como fazer isso com o `foreach`, com um for até sei resolver mas com `foreach` talvez pela pouco experiencia na linguagem não encontrei uma maneira.

O código esta dessa maneira no momento

```
 foreach ($results as $k => $v) {
        $html .= '
        <tr>
        <td>'.$v->nosso_numero.'</td>
        <td>'.$v->ocorrencia.'</td>
        <td>R$'.number_format($v->vlr_boleto, 2, ',', '.').'</td>
        <td>'.$v->matricula.'</td>
        <td>'.$v->nome.'</td>
        <td>'.$v->competencia.'</td>
        <td>R$'.number_format($v->valor_devido, 2, ',', '.').'</td>
        </tr>
';
    }
```

Eu gostaria de fazer uma comparação se

```
$results[n]->nosso_numero != $results[n-1]->nosso_numero
```

E montar baseado nessa verificação.

Comment: Já experimentou usar `array_unique($array)` ?

Comment: `array_unique` vai me retornar um novo array, eu preciso baseado no meu montar.

Comment: Tem como você inserir alguns itens do seu array $results?

Comment: Uma dúvida: esse array é gerado com base em uma consulta no banco de dados relacional? Uma alternativa, fora do PHP, seria utilizar um DISTINCT na hora de selecionar os dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens que considerar cada variável no seu `foreach`. Por exemplo:

> - `$results` : Lista de resultados
> - `$k` : Posição de sua lista (index)
> - `$v` : Item referente a posição

Considerando que a primeira posição não deve-se comparar com a anterior, a primeira condição é se o index é maior que 1. Assim:

```
if($k > 1)
```

A segunda condição é a comparação com o item anterior. Assim:

```
if($results[$k] !=$results[$k-1])
```

É possível fazer isso em apenas um if, usando as duas condições:

```
if($k > 1 && $results[$k] !=$results[$k-1])
```

O resultado final:

```
foreach ($results as $k => $v) {        
    if($k > 1 && $results[$k] !=$results[$k-1]){
        echo $v."\n";
    }                
}
```

**Obs.:** Desta forma, não irá remover os itens duplicado, mas sim oculta-los no momento da visualização.

---

É possível realizar este procedimento de remoção usando o método `array_unique($params)`, criando um novo *array* a partir da sua lista de itens repetidos. Veja:

```
$newResults = array_unique($results);
```